# How to select a word in a text SQL query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

On our PostgreSQL Database we have a field called Description. As you can guess this Description contains a lot of text and we would like to look inside this descriptions to find a certain word.

We tried contains and Charindex function but both are not working...

Any Idea how we can solve this?

Thank you very much!

Luca

Comment: Have you tried `LIKE`: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Description LIKE '%yourword%';` [Here is Postgresql page on pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with word delimiter markers:

```
select * from table
where description ~ ('\m' || 'yourword' || '\M');
```

Use `~*` instead of `~` for case insensitive searches.

Note that using description LIKE '%yourword%' as @JNevill suggests will find that your word within other words as well, e.g. `'Jean-Luc Picard' LIKE '%car%'` is true.